# Mysql Collation Enconding

Tags: php, android, mysql, collation

Well i am developing an app for android and my app is sending data to my database the problem is I want to to have different languages and I am having some problems keeping the names right due to Mysql Collation.

I mean if I send something like this: "José" the collation cuts me the word in to "Jos"(That's portuguese by the way) but if I want to use other language I cannot use the collation to UTF specif.

Is there any way to solve this?(Sorry for my poor English.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables are utf8 and you're transferring strings like 'José'. It might fix the issue if you set the connection collation to utf8, probably you're using different collations at some layer.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

This will be your first SQL query after you establish the connection.

More information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html

If you feel more comfortable with Portuguese there is the Portuguese version of Stackoverflow too, check it out: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I think the names are already utf8, I mean on phpMyAdmin is set as: "utf8_general_ci"already tried many others and nothing. I tried already your way I inserted in my PHP file:    $testing= mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); and it does not accept yet :S you have any other solution? By the way thanks very much for the tip for portuguese :) did not know about that

Comment: Can you add your table description here please ? (show create table tbl).

Comment: Sure here it is:

CREATE TABLE `os` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `latitude` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
 `longitude` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
 `Estrelas` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `Rua` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `dia` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `porta` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=83 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

The field not accepting is `Rua` I also tried with the char "ç" and nothing..

Comment: Actually if I change it on the myPHPADMIN there is no problem even if I do a query in myPHPADMIN there is no problem. The problem seems to be on my PHP file.. But i made an echo on my PHP file and the field '$Rua' appears right, which is even weirder

Comment: I found the mistake it appears I need to do something like this     $text2 = utf8_encode($Rua); !

Comment: Where is the field Rua coming from before going to the database ? Input ? You need to make sure everything is running with utf8 (Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc.)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad you found out! That makes sense, the field is coming with ISO-8859-1 probably, you need to convert to utf8 before insert in the database.